# Ado.net entity data model template missing in visual studio 2010

Tags: ado.net

Environment: Vista, VS2010 SP1

Apologize if I seem to be repeating this but I have spent a day on this. Last ditch attempt before I reinstall VS2010!!

I tried
1. devenv /installvstemplates
2. uninstalled EF 4.1 and installed 4.0 CTP 5 and now it's not even opening VS2010. Asking me to install SP1 again!!
I used Web Platform INstaller to install SP1 and EF.

Most of the posts was on VS2008 and different scenarios. SO really not sure what happened here.

Thanks in advance for your time

-Soni

Comment: Update: I restored Windows to version before installing EF. Will now look to install it again and see if it works.